# Unable to add multiple unity games in React Native App

Tags: react-native, unity-game-engine

I was using the following package: `@asmadsen/react-native-unity-view` [Link](https://github.com/asmadsen/react-native-unity-view) to show a unity game from my `react native` app.

This library has a component called `UnityView` which is responsible in showing the unity view of the game that we export from unity. It also has the code for exporting. So, that's not an issue.

What my issue is: I want to add multiple games to my `react native` app. And I am unable to understand what should I do to make it work.

Any suggestions is welcome. Thank you.